# Issue with converting a date-time string with timezone offset to local time in R

Tags: r, lubridate, posixct, posixlt

I'm facing difficulties converting a date-time string with a timezone offset to local time in R. The date-time string I have is in the following format: "2021-01-05T09:00:00+01:00". I want to convert it to the local time in the timezone specified by the offset (+01:00), which corresponds to Paris time (Europe/Paris) during the winter (CET - Central European Time).

I've tried using various methods, including lubridate and as.POSIXct() with the %z format. However, these attempts did not produce the correct result. For example, when using lubridate, the output is "2021-01-05 08:00:00 CET" instead of "2021-01-05 09:00:00 CET". I also attempted using strptime() with the same format, but the result remains incorrect.

Here's the R code I've tried so far:

```
moment <- "2021-01-05T09:00:00+01:00"
date_obj <- ymd_hms(moment) %>% force_tz(tzone = "Europe/Paris")
print(date_obj)  # Output: "2021-01-05 08:00:00 CET"

moment <- "2021-01-05T09:00:00+01:00"
date_obj <- ymd_hms(moment) %>% with_tz(tzone = "Europe/Paris")
print(date_obj)  # Output: "2021-01-05 09:00:00 CET"

# Using as.POSIXct()
moment <- "2021-01-05T09:00:00+01:00"
date_obj <- as.POSIXct(moment, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
print(date_obj)  # Output: NA

# Using strptime()
moment <- "2021-01-05T09:00:00+01:00"
date_obj <- strptime(moment, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S%z")
print(date_obj)  # Output: NA
```

Could someone please provide a clear and accurate solution to convert this date-time string to the local time in Paris (CET) with the specified timezone offset? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: seems promissing : anytime::anytime(moment,tz ="UTC" ,asUTC = TRUE) %>% with_tz("Europe/Paris")

Comment: `lubridate::parse_date_time(moment, "ymd_HMS_z",tz = "Europe/Paris")`

Comment: What's the problem with your 2nd approach in the question? Is that not the output you wanted?

Comment: In fact, you are absolutely right. I was convinced that the answer should be 10:00 AM and not 9:00 AM... All of this because of that darn daylight saving time.I was misled by the display of my Google Calendar, which is showing incorrect information. Thank you for taking the time to look into my issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify the format up to seconds and separately specify the time zone.  No packages are used.

```
moment <- "2021-01-05T09:00:00+01:00"

as.POSIXct(moment, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz = "Europe/Paris")
## [1] "2021-01-05 09:00:00 CET"
```

or

```
as.POSIXct(moment, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", tz = "CET")
## [1] "2021-01-05 09:00:00 CET"
```

or extract +01:00 and transform it to Etc/GMT-1 (note sign flip):

```
as.POSIXct(moment, format = "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S",
  tz = chartr("+-", "-+", sub(".*([+-])0?(.*):..$", "Etc/GMT\\1\\2", moment)))
## [1] "2021-01-05 09:00:00 +01"
```

Comment: Added third option.